# Find $(a+ib)^{492}$ given that $(a+ib)^{493}=1$

Tags: complex-numbers

We are given that: $(a+ib)^{493}=1$ .

Find the possible values of $(a+ib)^{492}$.

Comment: @Apurv: We only given the following information. The professor said that we had to think geometrically.

Comment: The question lacks information. It is obvious that the answer is $a-\iota b$ but its numerical value can't be found out with the data in the question...

Comment: I'll ask the professor and let you know what he says.

Answer (score 2):

If
$$
(a+ib)^{493}=1,
$$
then 
$$
|a+ib|=1
$$
and hence there exists a $\vartheta\in[0,2\pi)$, such that
$$
a+ib=\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta}.
$$
We know that
$$
\mathrm{e}^{493\vartheta i}=1,
$$
and hence
$493\vartheta=0\pmod{2\pi}$. Thus
$$
\vartheta=\frac{2k\pi}{493},
$$
for some $k=0,\ldots,492$, and hence
$$
(a+ib)^{492}=\mathrm{e}^{2\cdot 492k i\pi/493}=
\mathrm{e}^{984k\pi i/493}=\mathrm{e}^{-2k \pi i/493},
$$
for some $k=0,\ldots,492$.

That means 493 possible values!

Comment: An $i$ is missing in the last couple of exponentials.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z = re^{i\theta} = a+ib$

Now $(re^{i\theta})^{493} = 1$
Comparing, $r^{493} = 1$ hence $r = 1$.

Hence, $z^{492}\cdot z^{1} = 1$

Hence, $z^{492} = \dfrac{1}{z} = \dfrac{1}{a+ib} = \dfrac{a-ib}{a^2+b^2} = \dfrac{a-ib}{1} = a-ib$

The last step follows because $r = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} = 1$

Comment: You don't even need to write it in polar form. Just note that $1 = (a+ib)^{493} = (a+ib)^{492}(a+ib)$, giving $(a+ib)^{492} = \frac{1}{a+ib}$.

Comment: I know. But you somehow need to prove that $r = 1$ for $a+ib$. I just used it to make it obvious and easier to type that $a^2+b^2 = 1$.

Comment: Oh I see your point. Makes sense, then.

Answer (score 0):

(a+ib)^493 =1

=> (a+ib) = 1^(1/493) ; (a+ib)^492 = 1^(492/493) 
Let Z = c+id = 1+0i = 1 = cos(2nπ)-----------------------------------(n=integers)
=> Z^(492/493) = (a+ib)^492 = 1^(492/493) = {cos(2nπ)}^(492/493)
= {cos(984π)}^(1/493)------------------------------------------------(De moivre's theorem)
= {cos(2kπ+984π)}^(1/493)

Therefore, (a+ib)^492= {cos[(2kπ+984π)/493]}-------------------------(0<=K<493)

Answer (score 0):

We have $$(a+i b)^{493} \equiv 1 = e^{2\pi k i},\tag{1}$$ where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Hence, $$a+ib = e^{\frac{2\pi k i}{493}},$$ so $$ (a+ib)^{492}=e^{\frac{492}{493}2\pi ki}.\tag{2}$$ So long as $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfy (1) the formula on the right in (2) will give you the values you require as you run through all integers $k=\ldots,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,\ldots$ There will be a finite number of these answers (i.e. you will get repretitions eventually)